# Request takes too long (org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render())

Tags: spring, tomcat7, freemarker

I have a Java server (Tomcat7) running Spring.

In one of my pages its takes the server way to long to response! (more then 10 sec).

I'm adding here an image from Newrelic and the api actual code, there is no DB or any computation there simply returning the .ftl file to be rendered. (freemarker)

Any help will do!

What is ***org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render()*** and why its taking so long?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/lender", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String lender(@ModelAttribute("model") ModelMap model) {
    setGlobalAttributes(model);
    model.addAttribute("pageURL", "/lender");
    model.addAttribute("pageTitle", "title");
    model.addAttribute("pageDescription", "dsck
    model.addAttribute("documentTitle", "title");

    model.addAttribute("mixpanelCode", "mixpanelMoveLenderToStep('new');");

    return "lender-sign";
}
```

[image: screenshot from NewRelic]

Comment: According to your New Relic report, that method took on average 6ms to complete. It's your `lender-sign` template which takes 742ms to render, so the code you provide gives us no clue as to where your performance issues lie. Except to say that it's presumably Freemarker, which is taking its time.

Comment: Comment out parts of the template to find which part takes so long.